# Configuring logstash to work with multiple inputs

Tags: logstash

I currently have Logstash 5.5.1 installed and working on Windows Server 2012 r2 using the jdbc plugin against an SQL Server DB. My .conf file has an input with a `Select` statement and an elasticsearch output against an elastic index. I've also installed this as a service using nssm.

As you can imagine, I require more than 1 input and output. I don't mind creating n .conf files (1 for each query) if that's what I need to do, but I don't really want to have to create n services. I only want 1 service. Can anyone tell me how to do this? I've not found any documentation that really shows me how to set this kind of thing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put as many input directives as you want on the same logstash instance, just declare them in a conf file (either a single one or multiple ones).

```
input { ... }
input { ... }
...
output { ... }
```